# SELECT statement not working after INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle

So I've finished my first year programming so I know a bit about sql however I can't seem to find a solution/explanation to this problem.
I know you can execute statements after each other with ; but when I try to do it after an insert into [table] statement it doesn't work for me.
I've tried this so far:

```
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
VALUES(208, 'King', 'king@hotmail.com', sysdate, 'AC_MGR'); SELECT * FROM employees;
```

I always get an error saying the first semicolon is invalid.
Really would appreciate if someone could explain why it happens like this.
Also it only the `SELECT` statement that does this or is it every command after `INSERT INTO`

EDIT:

OP posted this image of the table definition as an answer. Just adding it here for everyone's sake.

[image]

EDIT2:
I did only use those values as an example, they weren't the actual values I used in my query but now I've updated them with the real values, still it makes no difference...

Comment: Can you show us your table schema?

Comment: Do you have a semicolon before "INSERT"?  I don't use mySQL, but the code you posted should work.

Comment: Is `id` an incremental id?

Comment: How do you run the query

Comment: Is your question about sql plus or MySQL?

Comment: If I'd auto incremental then do not include it and column should be same in select statement with datatype

Comment: Based on the information you posted in the answer (please add it to the question instead), you have a table with multiple columns defined as `NOT NULL`, meaning they cannot be empty. Yet, your `INSERT` statement only adds data to three columns. Unless you have `DEFAULT` values added to those `NOT NULL` columns, your insert will fail. You also are using the wrong column-names. There's no column called `name`, nor a column called job that accepts character data.

Comment: No comma after sysdate. Typo?

Comment: What happens if you run the insert statement without a semi-colon? Does the insert work? If so, then try and issue just the SELECT statement. Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know you can execute statements after each other with ;

As you have discovered, no you cannot.

With Oracle, there are two langauges to keep seperate. SQL, like what you are doing, and PL/SQL used in packages, functions, anonymous PL/SQL blocks, triggers, etc.

In PL/SQL the semicolon is a statement terminator, and can be used in the middle of a line to place more than one statement on the line, much like normal languages.

In Oracle's SQL a semicolon is **invalid**. What is confusing is that the **client** tools, such as SQLPlus use a semicolon **at the end of a line** as a terminator for SQL statements, but that semicolon is stripped before the statement is sent to the database server. The client is responsible for seperating the SQL statements before they are parsed by the server. Many other tools follow the lead of SQL*Plus in using the semicolon.

So, SQL*PLus, seeing `insert` says to itself, "A SQL statement" and then reads until a line ends with a semicolon. Then it sends what it read **minus** the trailing semicolon to the database server to execute a *single* SQL statement. Oracle's SQL parser doesn't know what to make of the internal semicolon and chokes.

Note, it is possible in SQLPlus to change the SQL statement terminator with [`set sqlterminator ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG109), but I have rarely seen that done in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the values clause and the semicolon in between what appears to be two statements and the statement should be like:-

```
INSERT INTO employees(EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, JOB_ID)
VALUES(1, 'king', 'manager') SELECT * FROM employees;
```

Comment: It gives an error (ORA-00993) saying SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @AwesomeFox So, messages starting in 'ORA' indicate that you're using Oracle and not MySQL. What is it that you are using?

Comment: Ty for the info, I adjusted the tag

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert-into
Please visit this for reference .

Comment: But the thing is, I'm not trying to select data to insert in the table. I'm trying to insert fixed data and immediately show that data. I'm just surprised it doesn't work when you do it in 1 line because if you do it in 2 steps, insert the values press enter and do the select it after it does work.
I was hoping maybe someone could clarify this behavior